# DocuSign Envelope draft tab values not showing up initially after populating data

Tags: docusignapi

We are using the DocuSign API to update the text tab values of a draft envelope that was created from a template so that once the envelope status is updated to 'sent' and the envelope is sent off to the first signer, the signer sees the values that were added to the text tabs (the values will be locked). When we test this out and the envelope is sent to the signer, the text tabs are  initially empty and only once they click "Finish" and the envelope is sent to the other signers does the values that were used show as expected to the other signers.

Ideally, we'd like this first signer to be able to view the populated values to make sure they are correct before it gets sent to the next signer. Below is the request body we are sending to `/envelopes/{ENVELOPE_ID}/recipients/{RECIPIENT_ID}/tabs` to update the values.

Any ideas why the text tabs values start off as blank? When we do the same thing for auto-placed tabs on an uploaded document (so not a template), everything works fine.

```
{
   "textTabs":[
      {
         "tabId":"b49d9173-2389-48e3-9bb4-ac8e50074d30",
         "tabLabel":"contractorestimatedenddate",
         "value":"01/31/2021",
         "bold":"true",
         "locked":"true"
      },
      {
         "tabId":"c86b92dc-92c3-430f-b4c7-97bb68906c70",
         "tabLabel":"contractorpop",
         "value":"John Doe",
         "bold":"true",
         "locked":"true"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: How are you finding the {RECIPIENT_ID} needed for this endpoint? Do you use the values from the template? you may need to ensure you are updating the correct recipient. I would suggest you share your entire code with how the envelope is created to help us help you.

Comment: Turns out `When an envelope is sent, write the initial value of the field for all recipients.` wasn't checked in settings. 

For what it's worth though, we are getting the recipient ID from the new envelope itself after creating a draft, rather than the template recipient ID.

Comment: Great, good information, happy Drew was able to figure this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for Settings > Sending Settings > *When an envelope is sent, write the initial value of the field for all recipients*.

Comment: That was it. Thank you!

Comment: Exactly the same issue I was having. Thanks!